# Word for feeding poultry?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a traditional or established word or phrase for the way one scatters food when feeding chickens or other animals that like to scratch, scrape, and search for food?  I’m translating a story and need a word/phrase to fill the following the gap:

> She fed the little hens, ___ing the corn.

Comment: Well, if you are doing a translation, that sentence needs improving on. She scattered the corn to feed the little hens. For example. Having scattering the corn hanging off the end there does not sound great to my ear.

Comment: It may only be a personal preference but I like "strew" better than "scatter."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original suggestion "scattering" sounds like the perfect fit to me.

Although it was much more common in the 19th century, it's still commonly used. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scattering%20the%20corn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,scattering%20the%20corn;,c0)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to do an ngram check.  "scattering" it is, then.